# Tensor product as module - standard terminology?

Tags: modules, terminology, tensor-products

In Dummit and Foote,2004; pg 375 they ask you to show that $\Bbb{C}\otimes_{\Bbb{C}}\Bbb{C}$ is a left $\Bbb{R}$-modules without clarification of the action. My question is; when something like this is posed is it standard to assume the action is:
$$r\left(\sum_{finite}a\otimes b\right)=\sum_{finite}(ra)\otimes b$$
in this case with $r\in \Bbb{R}$ and $a\otimes b\in \Bbb{C}\otimes_{\Bbb{C}}\Bbb{C}$. If this is not standard/what they mean then what is?

I am interested in the general case of e.g. $M\otimes_R N$ as a $S$-modules - not just the case presented here as an example. Here $R$ and $S$ are rings with $1$ and are possibly non-commutative. $M$ and $N$ have to be at least $R$-modules.

Comment: Elaborate in your PS what types of rings $R$ and $S$ are and what type of modules (over which rings) $M$ and $N$ are. (Separately, a general tensor is not of the form $a\otimes b$, so your formula for scaling on the tensor product is not the general case.)

Comment: @KCd I have edited the bit about the about the general tensor. Does the type of ring matter? Also I think in this case both $M$ and $N$ would need to be both $R$ and $S$ - modules?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification in that general case, it would very much help if one of $M$ or $N$ was some sort of $S$ module. Otherwise, what could you action possibly do? You'd have to get pretty creative.

Comment: @MikePierce Ok, great thanks. I think I understand it all now.

Comment: I meant, about the rings, if they were commutative or not. In Dummit & Foote they first treat tensor products of modules over possibly noncommutative rings, where the tensor product has less structure than when working over commutative rings. Not everyone has D&F in front of them to know what the assumptions about commutativity if rings are on p. 375.

Comment: Okay, please put that in the body of the question so it is more visible when people read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's typically the natural action to consider. But then you have to *prove* that it is a valid left action.

In general, to prove something is a left $R$-module, it just has to have *some* action of $R$ defined on the left. You get to pick that action, and usually it turns out to be a very natural choice. In the general case, part of the exercise is deciding what the "natural action" is.

Comment: I disagree with this. There is no such thing as proving that "something is a left $R$-module". Here by "something" you have to mean an Abelian group. In which case it's not an $R$-module, it's an Abelian group.

Comment: @user2520938 Isn't that a natural part of the definition of a module? It's an abelian group with an action of $R$ defined on it that agrees with the group structure. When you are handed an object $M\otimes_R N$ and asked to show that it's an $R$ module, it's often pretty obvious that $M\otimes_R N$ is a group already, so the *purpose* of the exercise is defining the action.

Comment: The sentence that an Abelian group IS an $R$-module just doesn't make sense. An Abelian group is an Abelian group, not an $R$-module.

Comment: @user2520938 But... Abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.  Lots of things can be modules and other things too.  Another example would be a vector space with some prescribed linear transformation being an $F[x]$-module.  The more relevant example would be that a tensor product, as given, is an abelian group.  If $M$ is a left module over some ring or if $N$ is a right module over some ring, then we can naturally define a module structure on the tensor product.  We could also naturally define an action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on the tensor product just as easily.  After all, it's an abelian group.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost i know all that, but still disagree and am suprised that you dont. An $R$-module is a pair of an abelian group and an action of $R$. An abelian group is not that (at most you can remark, as you did, that there is a canonical $Z$ action, so it is a $Z$ module). Its Just a fact that the category of abelian groups is not the same as the category of $R$ modules for most R, so saying that an abelian group is an R module is just wrong. A topological space isn't manifold until you chose an atlas, an abelian group isnt an R module until you chose an action. Should be obvious.

Comment: All this hoopla is over the use (or misuse) of the word "*is*."